# Multi relation foreign keys

Tags: mysql, laravel

If I have 3 tables:

User, Conversation, Messages

Between User and conversation I have:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('users')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
```

And between conversation and messages:

```
$table->foreign('conversation_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('conversations')
                  ->onDelete('restrict');
```

If someone accidentally try to delete conversation, it should stop him because of messages restriction. But same way user is deleted I want to delete both conversation and messages.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways that you can do it, one of the way would be as follow in your `User` model

```
class User extends Model 
{
    public static function boot()
    {
       static::deleting(function ($model) {

            // Remember that $model here is an instance of User

           // Loop over conversations and delete
          $model->conversations->each(function($conversation){

              $conversation = tap($conversation)->delete();

              // loop over the messages and delete
              $conversation->messages->each(function($message){
                    $message->delete();
              }):

          });

    });
  }
}
```

Hope that helps. You can also use observer class or have it in your app service provider. Look into laravel events

Answer (score 0):

*onDelete('cascade');* simply adds ON DELETE CASCADE rule to your database which specifies that the child data gets deleted when the parent data is deleted.

So if your parent data (*user*) is deleted, all child data (*conversations*) also gets deleted.

If you change '*->onDelete('restrict');*' to '*->onDelete('cascade');*' you will enforce the same rule thats in place for the *user* table (assuming *conversations* is your parent data and *messages* is your child data)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score -1):

you should add `onDelete('cascade');` on both relation. first one will remove all message and second one will remove every conversation with each message.

You have to change the 
 between conversation and messages:

```
$table->foreign('conversation_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('conversations')
                  ->onDelete('cascade'); //change restrict to cascade
```

Comment: Sorry if i wrong. I read the question again. and what i understand is,
you are going to delete an user, and it will automatic remove the conversations and messages. [I assume, the relation is, user > conversations > message.]. If this is the relation, then it will work.

Comment: If you cannot change the database, then you let us know.